# Finding memory usage of a process in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to find the current memory usage of a particular process. Every guide I've found online so far gives instructions on how to get the usage as a percentage of total memory. I want thr process' ram usae as a discrete value (i.e. in megabytes).

Answer (score 11):

To only **get a *single* memory-usage number of interest**, try (`$pid` is a placeholder for the PID of interest; in `bash`, use `$$` to refer to the current shell process, for instance):

```
 ps -o rss= $pid   # resident set in kbytes; e.g., 2461016
 ps -o vsz= $pid   # virtual size in kbytes; e.g., 1048
```

As [Sammitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1064767/sammitch) points out, a way to get *both* values in a single space-separated output line is:

```
 ps -o vsz=,rss= $pid
```

To **convert a single value to MB** (rounded to an integer, adjust as needed), try something like:

```
ps -o rss= $pid | awk '{printf "%.0f\n", $1 / 1024}' # e.g., 1
```

In [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), you can simplify to (note that `$PID` there actually refers to the shell's process itself, analogous to `$$` in POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`):

```
(ps -o rss= $pid) / 1mb  # e.g., 1.0443000793457031
```

Answer (score 5):

If you know the process ID:

```
cat /proc/$pid/status
```

If you want the usage from within the process:

```
cat /proc/self/status # or read the file with fopen() or whatnot
```

Which will output something like:

```
# cat /proc/7049/status
Name:   bash
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   7049
Pid:    7049
PPid:   7042
TracerPid:      0
Uid:    500     500     500     500
Gid:    500     500     500     500
Utrace: 0
FDSize: 256
Groups: 10 500
VmPeak:   108524 kB
VmSize:   108492 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmHWM:      2080 kB
VmRSS:      2072 kB
VmData:      532 kB
VmStk:        88 kB
VmExe:       848 kB
VmLib:      1876 kB
VmPTE:        60 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
Threads:        1
SigQ:   0/14888
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000010000
SigIgn: 0000000000384004
SigCgt: 000000004b813efb
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: ffffffffffffffff
Cpus_allowed:   1
Cpus_allowed_list:      0
Mems_allowed:   00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000001
Mems_allowed_list:      0
voluntary_ctxt_switches:        164
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:     4
```

The `Vm*` fields contain the information you seek.

Note: the exact format of this can vary from distro to distro.

Or, more simply:

```
ps up $pid
```

Which gives something like:

```
# ps up 7049
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
stack     7049  0.0  0.1 108492  2072 pts/0    Ss   20:23   0:00 -bash
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
ps aux --sort=%mem,%cpu
```

To sort all running processes by their memory & CPU usage.

If you want to limit to just the process which you are running from the current terminal:

```
ps v
```

If you know the pid use:

```
ps v <pid>
```

Example output:

```
PID    TTY STAT  TIME PGIN  SIZE   RSS   LIM  TSIZ   TRS %CPU %MEM COMMAND
36626  pts/3 A     0:00    0   316   408 32768    51    60  0.0  0.0 ps v
```

where

**PGIN**
Number of page-ins caused by page faults. Since all I/O is classified as page faults, this is basically a measure of I/O volume.

**SIZE**
Virtual size (in paging space) in kilobytes of the data section of the process (displayed as SZ by other flags). This number is equal to the number of working segment pages of the process that have been touched times 4. If some working segment pages are currently paged out, this number is larger than the amount of real memory being used. SIZE includes pages in the private segment and the shared-library data segment of the process.

**RSS**
Real-memory (resident set) size in kilobytes of the process. This number is equal to the sum of the number of working segment and code segment pages in memory times 4. Remember that code segment pages are shared among all of the currently running instances of the program. If 26 ksh processes are running, only one copy of any given page of the ksh executable program would be in memory, but the ps command would report that code segment size as part of the RSS of each instance of the ksh program.

**TSIZ**
Size of text (shared-program) image. This is the size of the text section of the executable file. Pages of the text section of the executable program are only brought into memory when they are touched, that is, branched to or loaded from. This number represents only an upper bound on the amount of text that could be loaded. The TSIZ value does not reflect actual memory usage. This TSIZ value can also be seen by executing the dump -ov command against an executable program (for example, dump -ov /usr/bin/ls).

**TRS**
Size of the resident set (real memory) of text. This is the number of code segment pages times 4. This number exaggerates memory use for programs of which multiple instances are running. The TRS value can be higher than the TSIZ value because other pages may be included in the code segment such as the XCOFF header and the loader section.

**%MEM**
Calculated as the sum of the number of working segment and code segment pages in memory times 4 (that is, the RSS value), divided by the size of the real memory in use, in the machine in KB, times 100, rounded to the nearest full percentage point. This value attempts to convey the percentage of real memory being used by the process. Unfortunately, like RSS, it tends the exaggerate the cost of a process that is sharing program text with other processes. Further, the rounding to the nearest percentage point causes all of the processes in the system that have RSS values under 0.005 times real memory size to have a %MEM of 0.0.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to learn about the [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) and the [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) used by your [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) since e.g. [C memory management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_memory_management) (i.e. [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) etc...) is consuming (and releasing) virtual memory (gotten with [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) etc...).

Then you should use the `/proc/` file system (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) ....). In particular, for process of pid 1234, try `cat /proc/1234/maps` and `cat /proc/1234/status`. See also [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) and try `pmap 1234`

BTW, `/proc/` is the way the kernel gives information about processes (and most system status; see also `/sys/`). In particular, `ps`, `top`, `pmap`, `htop` are all using `/proc/`

FWIW, I'm using `zsh` as my interactive shell, and here is what `cat /proc/$$/maps` gives me:

```
 00400000-004a5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2883633                            /bin/zsh5
 006a4000-006a5000 r--p 000a4000 08:01 2883633                            /bin/zsh5
 006a5000-006ab000 rw-p 000a5000 08:01 2883633                            /bin/zsh5
 006ab000-006bf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 01e5c000-01faf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
 7f2fa1533000-7f2fa1564000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f2fa1564000-7f2fa1574000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1049819                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/computil.so
 7f2fa1574000-7f2fa1773000 ---p 00010000 08:01 1049819                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/computil.so
 7f2fa1773000-7f2fa1774000 r--p 0000f000 08:01 1049819                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/computil.so
 7f2fa1774000-7f2fa1775000 rw-p 00010000 08:01 1049819                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/computil.so
 7f2fa1775000-7f2fa1785000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f2fa1785000-7f2fa1788000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1049839                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/rlimits.so
 7f2fa1788000-7f2fa1988000 ---p 00003000 08:01 1049839                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/rlimits.so
 7f2fa1988000-7f2fa1989000 r--p 00003000 08:01 1049839                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/rlimits.so
 7f2fa1989000-7f2fa198a000 rw-p 00004000 08:01 1049839                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/rlimits.so
 7f2fa198a000-7f2fa19c0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f2fa19c0000-7f2fa19c3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1049830                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/stat.so
 7f2fa19c3000-7f2fa1bc2000 ---p 00003000 08:01 1049830                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/stat.so
 7f2fa1bc2000-7f2fa1bc3000 r--p 00002000 08:01 1049830                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/stat.so
 7f2fa1bc3000-7f2fa1bc4000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 1049830                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/stat.so
 7f2fa1bc4000-7f2fa1bcd000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1055723                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/parameter.so
 7f2fa1bcd000-7f2fa1dcd000 ---p 00009000 08:01 1055723                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/parameter.so
 7f2fa1dcd000-7f2fa1dce000 r--p 00009000 08:01 1055723                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/parameter.so
 7f2fa1dce000-7f2fa1dcf000 rw-p 0000a000 08:01 1055723                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/parameter.so
 7f2fa1dcf000-7f2fa1dd6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1056697                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/zutil.so
 7f2fa1dd6000-7f2fa1fd5000 ---p 00007000 08:01 1056697                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/zutil.so
 7f2fa1fd5000-7f2fa1fd6000 r--p 00006000 08:01 1056697                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/zutil.so
 7f2fa1fd6000-7f2fa1fd7000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 1056697                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/zutil.so
 7f2fa1fd7000-7f2fa1ff9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1049816                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/complete.so
 7f2fa1ff9000-7f2fa21f9000 ---p 00022000 08:01 1049816                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/complete.so
 7f2fa21f9000-7f2fa21fa000 r--p 00022000 08:01 1049816                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/complete.so
 7f2fa21fa000-7f2fa21fb000 rw-p 00023000 08:01 1049816                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/complete.so
 7f2fa21fb000-7f2fa21fc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f2fa21fc000-7f2fa223d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1049825                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/zle.so
 7f2fa223d000-7f2fa243d000 ---p 00041000 08:01 1049825                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/zle.so
 7f2fa243d000-7f2fa243e000 r--p 00041000 08:01 1049825                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/zle.so
 7f2fa243e000-7f2fa2445000 rw-p 00042000 08:01 1049825                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/zle.so
 7f2fa2445000-7f2fa2446000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f2fa2446000-7f2fa2448000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1055724                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/terminfo.so
 7f2fa2448000-7f2fa2647000 ---p 00002000 08:01 1055724                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/terminfo.so
 7f2fa2647000-7f2fa2648000 r--p 00001000 08:01 1055724                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/terminfo.so
 7f2fa2648000-7f2fa2649000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 1055724                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.0.5/zsh/terminfo.so
 7f2fa2649000-7f2fa2655000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4985164                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.18.so
 7f2fa2655000-7f2fa2854000 ---p 0000c000 08:01 4985164                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.18.so
 7f2fa2854000-7f2fa2855000 r--p 0000b000 08:01 4985164                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.18.so
 7f2fa2855000-7f2fa2856000 rw-p 0000c000 08:01 4985164                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.18.so
 7f2fa2856000-7f2fa2860000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4985173                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.18.so
 7f2fa2860000-7f2fa2a5f000 ---p 0000a000 08:01 4985173                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.18.so
 7f2fa2a5f000-7f2fa2a60000 r--p 00009000 08:01 4985173                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.18.so
 7f2fa2a60000-7f2fa2a61000 rw-p 0000a000 08:01 4985173                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.18.so
 7f2fa2a61000-7f2fa2a76000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4985159                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.18.so
 7f2fa2a76000-7f2fa2c75000 ---p 00015000 08:01 4985159                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.18.so
 7f2fa2c75000-7f2fa2c76000 r--p 00014000 08:01 4985159                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.18.so
 7f2fa2c76000-7f2fa2c77000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 4985159                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.18.so
 7f2fa2c77000-7f2fa2c79000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f2fa2c79000-7f2fa2c80000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4985166                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.18.so
 7f2fa2c80000-7f2fa2e7f000 ---p 00007000 08:01 4985166                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.18.so
 7f2fa2e7f000-7f2fa2e80000 r--p 00006000 08:01 4985166                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.18.so
 7f2fa2e80000-7f2fa2e81000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 4985166                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.18.so
 7f2fa2e81000-7f2fa2e85000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4980783                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1.1.0
 7f2fa2e85000-7f2fa3084000 ---p 00004000 08:01 4980783                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1.1.0
 7f2fa3084000-7f2fa3085000 r--p 00003000 08:01 4980783                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1.1.0
 7f2fa3085000-7f2fa3086000 rw-p 00004000 08:01 4980783                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1.1.0
 7f2fa3086000-7f2fa3226000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4985168                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.18.so
 7f2fa3226000-7f2fa3425000 ---p 001a0000 08:01 4985168                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.18.so
 7f2fa3425000-7f2fa3429000 r--p 0019f000 08:01 4985168                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.18.so
 7f2fa3429000-7f2fa342b000 rw-p 001a3000 08:01 4985168                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.18.so
 7f2fa342b000-7f2fa342f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f2fa342f000-7f2fa3530000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4985165                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.18.so
 7f2fa3530000-7f2fa3730000 ---p 00101000 08:01 4985165                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.18.so
 7f2fa3730000-7f2fa3731000 r--p 00101000 08:01 4985165                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.18.so
 7f2fa3731000-7f2fa3732000 rw-p 00102000 08:01 4985165                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.18.so
 7f2fa3732000-7f2fa3757000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4980894                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
 7f2fa3757000-7f2fa3957000 ---p 00025000 08:01 4980894                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
 7f2fa3957000-7f2fa395b000 r--p 00025000 08:01 4980894                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
 7f2fa395b000-7f2fa395c000 rw-p 00029000 08:01 4980894                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
 7f2fa395c000-7f2fa395f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4985160                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.18.so
 7f2fa395f000-7f2fa3b5e000 ---p 00003000 08:01 4985160                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.18.so
 7f2fa3b5e000-7f2fa3b5f000 r--p 00002000 08:01 4985160                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.18.so
 7f2fa3b5f000-7f2fa3b60000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 4985160                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.18.so
 7f2fa3b60000-7f2fa3b64000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4980821                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2.22
 7f2fa3b64000-7f2fa3d63000 ---p 00004000 08:01 4980821                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2.22
 7f2fa3d63000-7f2fa3d64000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 4980821                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2.22
 7f2fa3d64000-7f2fa3d84000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4985158                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.18.so
 7f2fa3d85000-7f2fa3d91000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f2fa3d91000-7f2fa3f59000 r--p 00000000 08:01 7083454                    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
 7f2fa3f59000-7f2fa3f5e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f2fa3f60000-7f2fa3f70000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f2fa3f72000-7f2fa3f7a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f2fa3f7a000-7f2fa3f81000 r--s 00000000 08:01 7112364                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
 7f2fa3f81000-7f2fa3f83000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f2fa3f83000-7f2fa3f84000 r--p 0001f000 08:01 4985158                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.18.so
 7f2fa3f84000-7f2fa3f85000 rw-p 00020000 08:01 4985158                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.18.so
 7f2fa3f85000-7f2fa3f86000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7ffff69af000-7ffff69d0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
 7ffff69fe000-7ffff6a00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
 ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Read also about [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR) and read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

Answer (score -2):

In the Terminal you can run `top`. It will give you a KiloByte representation of the memory usage per process. You can even use `grep` to make a snapshot of a certain process' usage.

Comment: In mine, it gives %mem per process

Comment: If you're using Debian/Ubuntu. Install `htop` `sudo apt-get install htop`

Comment: I have htop, same thing (also, I'm on arch)

Comment: You can try option `o`, `p` or `q`. See the docs: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?top+1