# Given a user calculate how many bytes their process are consuming

Tags: linux, bash

I'm working with linux and I want to make a script that gets an username in the input and it returns the memory that their proccess are consuming.

How can I achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to measure actual memory usage of an application or process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/131303/608639), [Finding memory usage of a process in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22261452/608639), [Retrieve CPU usage and memory usage of a single process on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1221555/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use top command and get the memory usage by parsing the output and looking for "KiB Mem :"

```
top -u <UserId> -n 1 | grep "Mem :" | awk '{print $8}'
```

You need to change the grep pattern to pick the right line

Comment: While tryng to put my UserId in the command bash gives an error saying that file or directory doesn't exist, any idea why is that happening?

Comment: I haven't seen that error. Also you should use the userid which you use to login to the unix system.

Answer (score -1):

You can try also:

`ps -u<username> -o %mem,size,pid,cmd`

This will display the percentage of memory used, the size in kilobytes,process id and the process itself(command).
If you want to check the total memory for one use only:

`ps -u<username> -o size |awk 'NR>1{s+=$1}END{print s}'`

Check the man page of `ps` command for more options to display.